# What do the symbols in the left-most column of ncdu mean?

Tags: command-line

OS: Kubuntu 16.04 and `ncdu` version 1.11.

When I run

```
ncdu -x /
```

I get

```
--- / --------------------------------------
.  97.1 GiB [##########] /home              
    4.6 GiB [          ] /usr
  718.8 MiB [          ] /lib
. 562.4 MiB [          ] /var
  177.8 MiB [          ] /opt
  143.2 MiB [          ] /boot
   12.7 MiB [          ] /bin
.  11.1 MiB [          ] /etc
   11.0 MiB [          ] /sbin
. 100.0 KiB [          ] /tmp
   36.0 KiB [          ] /mnt
.  16.0 KiB [          ] /media
!  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
    4.0 KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /srv
!   4.0 KiB [          ] /root
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /cdrom
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
>   0.0   B [          ] /sys
>   0.0   B [          ] /run
>   0.0   B [          ] /proc
>   0.0   B [          ] /dev
```

What do `.`, `!`, `e`, `@`, and `>` mean? `man ncdu` and `info ncdu` don't have any information on the meaning of these symbols.

`man du` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While in `ncdu`, press <kbd>?</kbd> to show help, then <kbd>2</kbd> to show the formatting help.

Here it is :

```
┌───ncdu help─────────────────1:Keys───2:Format───3:About──┐
│                                                          │
│  X  [size] [graph] [file or directory]                   │
│   The X is only present in the following cases:          │
│                                                          │
│   !  An error occured while reading this directory       │
│   .  An error occured while reading a subdirectory       │
│   <  File or directory is excluded from the statistics   │
│   >  Directory was on an other filesystem                │
│   @  This is not a file nor a dir (symlink, socket, ...) │
│   H  Same file was already counted (hard link)           │
│   e  Empty directory                                     │
│                                                          │
│                                         Press q to close │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried `ncdu -h` when `ncdu` wasn't running.